# Probablity of Boy

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I faced this question in a coding contest.

The ratio of boys to girls for babies born in Russia is 1.09 : 1  . If there is 1 child born per birth, what proportion of Russian families with exactly 6 children will have at least 3 boys?

I am new to probability. Though I have studied about binomial distribution just now but still not able to lead with this question.
Can anybody help with detailed answer.

Comment: you're missing part of your questions : no number of total children and boys are specified.

Comment: @TMM Thanks for pointing. Corrected.  Please see now.

Comment: @WNG : Please see the question now.
This is the complete info available as per question that i faced.

Comment: @JohnDoe Already corrected

Comment: This question is exactly about binomials, so if you studied that then you should be able to solve it. First, what is the probability of a child being a boy? Second, ask yourself what binomial probability are you looking to compute?

Comment: You say this is a question from a coding contest. Doesn't that mean you could solve it by coding the problem? For instance simulate Russian families?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is what proportion of Russian families with exactly $n$ children will have at least $k$ boys?

The number of boys in a russian family of $n$ kids has a Binomial distribution of parameters $n$ and $p=\frac{1.09}{2.09}$

Which means that they will have exactly $k$ children with probability

$C^k_np^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Thus the probability of having at least $k$ children is :

$\sum_{i=k}^nC^i_np^i(1-p)^{n-i}=1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}C^i_np^i(1-p)^{n-i}$

There is, to my knowledge, no exact simplification of this formula

Well, just replace $n$ with 6 and $k$ with 3.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to arrange the permutations of BBBGGG (b for boy, g for girl). This is so that we can find all ways a family of 6 can have 3 boys ad 3 girls in some order.

First, there is a $(\frac{1.09}{2.09})^3(\frac{1}{2.09})^3$ chance that this situation even arises. But there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to arrange the given sequence, so the answer is just $\boxed{\binom{6}{3}(\frac{1.09}{2.09})^3(\frac{1}{2.09})^3}$ which is around 31.1%.

Comment: PS: That's for *exactly 3*.  At least 3 is $$\binom 6 3 (\tfrac{1.09}{2.09})^3(\tfrac{1}{2.09})^3+\binom 6 4 (\tfrac{1.09}{2.09})^4(\tfrac{1}{2.09})^2+\binom 6 5 (\tfrac{1.09}{2.09})^5(\tfrac{1}{2.09})^1+\binom 6 6 (\tfrac{1.09}{2.09})^6(\tfrac{1}{2.09})^0$$

Comment: the problem got me. :)